# How to make content widget similar like view zone?

Tags: monaco-editor

Here I can use content widget to have an input control where I can enter some text, and a content widget can be placed exactly on a line and column, but it overlays the existing text.

I found that view zone solution. It does not overlay the existing text, but it only supports a full line. Here I want to use content widget with specific width, and I hope it will not overlay the text area, let's say that this content widget can be inserted between some text.

How I can implement this feature? Any suggestion?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. View zones can only be attached between lines. That's how they are designed.